# Using Mail gem, and my ruby code is not rendering. Any ideas?

Tags: ruby, email

Im using Sinatra and this gem, and Im able to send email ok. However, when I send an ERB file, it comes through as plain text and it doesnt render the ruby code. For example:

```
mail = Mail.deliver do
  to user_email
  from 'support@iconosites.com'
  subject 'Your Upgrade is being processed'
  body File.read('views/email.erb')
end
```

Is there a way to have it render the Ruby code?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it looks like you're trying to render an erb template as the body of your email.

I think you'd need to do something more along the lines of:

```
require 'erb'
template = ERB.new(File.read('views/email.erb'))

mail = Mail.deliver do
  to user_email
  from 'support@iconosites.com'
  subject 'Your Upgrade is being processed'
  body template.result
end
```

There's a couple of email examples on the ruby-docs page for erb templates here also: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html